# How to select all label elements inside table with specific class

Tags: css

**Table**

```
<table id="tab1" class="table labelCustom">
   <tbody>
        <tr><td><label>example</label></td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

How can i access with css all label that will be inside td's of table with class **`labelCustom`**?

Comment: This might help you: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
table.labelCustom td label {
    //your css styles
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`table.labelCustom > tbody > tr > td > label` will be the most specific as this will only select labels that are children of the `td` elements and not every `label` within those `td` elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy:

```
.labelCustom td label {
    *Properties Here*
}
```

Can see the results here: [This isn't a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjsg08/dcstkssp/)